# Defining friend function inside class declaration

Tags: c++, class, friend-function, function-definition

I have found that friend function can be defined inside class declaration. I am a little bit confused about what does it mean due to a class declaration does not provide it's body, in general it just `class A;`.

> Friend functions can be defined (given a function body) inside class
>   declarations. These functions are inline functions, and like member
>   inline functions they behave as though they were defined immediately
>   after all class members have been seen but before the class scope is
>   closed (the end of the class declaration). Friend functions that are
>   defined inside class declarations are in the scope of the enclosing
>   class.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/friend-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: My guess is that it's just a mistake, and they mean "inside a class *definition*"

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) seems to say that `class A;` is a forward declaration, and `class A { /* ... */ }` would also be a declaration (it would declare the members of the class). https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632 seems to disagree. I thought that all definitions were also declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It means that

```
class A
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const A&a)
    {
        return os << a.m1 << a.m2;
    }
};
```

is equivalent to

```
class A
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const A&a);
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const A&a)
{
    return os << a.m1 << a.m2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class declaration can be at the same time a class definition.

You can not place a friend function definition in a class that is not being defined.

Take into account that if such a friend function is not also declared outside the class granting the friendship then it is invisible. It can be found only by the argument dependent name lookup.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    int x;

public:
    A( int x ) : x ( x ) {}
    operator int() const { return x; }
    friend void f( const A &a )
    {
        std::cout << "a.x = " << a.x << '\n';
    }
};

void f( int x )
{
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    f( A( 10 ) );
    ( f )( A( 20 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a.x = 10
x = 20
```

In this call

```
f( A( 10 ) );
```

the name of the friend function is found due to the argument dependent lookup.

In this call

```
( f )( A( 20 ) );
```

enclosing the function name in parentheses switches off the argument dependent look up and the non-friend function is called.

Or you could use a qualified function name like

```
::f( A( 20 ) );
```

In this case the ADL also will not work and the non-friend function will be called.

Also bear in mind that friend function defined in a class is in the lexical scope of the class. It means that it can use names of members of the class. Friend function defined outside a class is not in the lexical scope of the class.